# parent.controls.add

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling

Problem with `controls.add(pic)`

```
private void blockRoadMouseMove(System.Object sender,
          System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            if (Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Control)
            {
                int yo = this.Location.Y;
                int startx = this.Left;
                int cx = startx;
                int mo = e.X + this.Left - clickOffsetX;

                DrawingControl.SuspendDrawing(mainPic);
                mainPic.SuspendLayout();
                blockRoad pic = new blockRoad(mainPic);
                DrawingControl.SuspendDrawing(pic);

                for (int t = cx; t < mo; t += 20)
                {
                    pic.setChar(this.Image, t, yo);
                }
                mainPic.ResumeLayout();
                DrawingControl.ResumeDrawing(mainPic);
            }
        }
    }
```

I used that

```
class DrawingControl
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 wMsg, bool wParam, Int32 lParam);

        private const int WM_SETREDRAW = 11;

        public static void SuspendDrawing(Control parent)
        {
            SendMessage(parent.Handle, WM_SETREDRAW, false, 0);
        }

        public static void ResumeDrawing(Control parent)
        {
            SendMessage(parent.Handle, WM_SETREDRAW, true, 0);
            parent.Refresh();
        }
    }
```

The problem is add many (pic) in one position next position add many ..next add...

in (every) one position add many pic
I want to add (one) pic in every position

Comment: Sorry, but i can't understand what you want to do.

Comment: I don't see "ctr" anywhere in your code. Your current code also doesn't compile (parenthesis issues?) If you don't put any effort into asking your question, you won't get any effort in answers.

Comment: i add more code, i hope it clear now

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by add just (check) 
if  blockRoad is NOT locate in this location (add)

```
for (int t = cx; t < mo; t += 20)
{
    Control c = pic.GetChildAtPoint(new Point(cx, y));

    if (c == null)
    {
        pic.setChar(this.Image, t, yo);
        pic.Controls.Add(pic);
    }
}
```

if there another solution, i hope i know
thanks